# How to use jQuery tabs to show three tabs of three different views?

Tags: views, javascript

I have three separate Content Types, with three table Views for each, and they are being displayed in three separate pages. But now I want to use jQuery UI Tabs to have just one page with three tabs. How do I do this? Do I need to change the View to display a Block instead of a page and go from there? Where in Drupal do I install jQuery Tabs at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module.

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can
>   create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with
>   corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding
>   content display instantly, using jQuery.

I used it before and it's working great.